# How to delete an element in an index of a 2D array. Its giving an argument error

Tags: python

I want to delete the second last element of my first array.
And I did this :

```
array=[[9,0,8,2,5]]
length=len(array)
for i in range(length):
    print(array[i])
    
array.insert(0,[3,7,2,9])
print(array)

array[0][2]=50
print(array)

array.pop(1,[3])
print(array)
```

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: OK. What happened when you did that, and how is it different from what you expected?

Comment: `.pop()` takes a single argument, the index. You have passed it 2. `array[1].pop(3)` is what you want

Comment: Can you remove the operations like the insert and assign that are not related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

To drop by index, try:

```
del array[i][j]
```

where i is the sub array and j is the element of sub array (-1 for last element)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the way you are using the `list.pop` method. It only supports [up to one argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

The solution your probably looking for is probably `array[1].pop(3)`

Also, you can use negative indexes like `array[-1].pop(-2)` to remove the second to last element of the last array.